# How to get Landscape running on MAAS on Ubuntu OrangeBox?

Tags: maas, landscape, openstack-autopilot, orange-box

We have purchased several Ubuntu OrangeBoxes, and are trying to get a prototype environment running, but it's proving to be difficult as there is very little documentation or contact points available for the Orange Box.

After struggling for a long time with several functions in the tech stack not working properly behind a proxy (boot image sync, juju ++), we're now stuck at Landscape deployment on MAAS.

Initial connection to MAAS in Landscape fails on install prerequisites check, as Landscape requires a minimum of 5 nodes with 2 HDDs available in MAAS to continue. The NUCs in the OrangeBox only have one HDD each, so the install will not run.

Please advise.

Answer (score 6):

The OpenStack Autopilot is built for server-class hardware. If you want to use NUCs you'll have to modify them to act like server-class hardware (add USB keys that act like second disks, add a USB NIC to one of them so it has two wired NICs to use for Neutron, etc).

In terms of bootstrapping the orange box, you can use some helper scripts found at https://launchpad.net/orange-box

Comment: Thank you for your response. I realize now that extra hw is required for the OrangeBox to function properly, I was just checking whether any tricks or hacks existed to remedy the situation. It is incredibly frustrating to spend a lot of money on these boxes (that are marketed with amongst other things with "Deploy OpenStack, Hadoop, CloudFoundry, and hundreds of other workloads in minutes"), and struggle to find information, documentation or other input on how to get them working.